# Pass a Custom Authorization Token to the Backend

Tags: wso2

I am trying to send a custom token to an existing API via WSO2.

As in, I have a token for the backend API and I want it included in the header WSO2 sends to that API.

All google queries appear to lead to [this](https://docs.wso2.com/display/APICloud/Pass+a+Custom+Authorization+Token+to+the+Backend) page. Unfortunately, those instructions assume WSO2 cloud, where I am using a local install.

Are there instructions on how to do this with a local install? Preferably without Eclipse? Even more preferably within the WSO2 GUI?

Thanks!

EDIT:

As per an answer below, I've made some progress. Going from [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Adding+Mediation+Extensions#AddingMediationExtensions-CreateanduploadmanuallyintheAPIPublisher), I've added this bit of xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="default-endpoint-seq">
     <property name="Authorization" value="<valid token>" scope="transport"/>
</sequence>
```

and then added it to the "Message Mediation Policies" section under "inflow"

[image]

Sadly, I'm still getting forbidden. Seeing as I only have the dimmest idea what is going on here, that's probably not surprising.

[EDIT 3]

Cleaning up now that I have it working. The process above (and below) does work. Be sure to add "Bearer" to the xml...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="default-endpoint-seq">
     <property name="Authorization" value="Bearer <valid token>" scope="transport"/>
</sequence>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 ways you can do this.

1) You can save backend password, in APIM itself. Refer below docs.

Set a password for a backend endpoint:

https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Basic+Auth
https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Digest+Auth

Encrypt that password:

https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Encrypting+Secure+Endpoint+Passwords

2) You can send the backend token in the request itself and let APIM pass it to the backend. You can create a sequence like this and attach to APIs.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="default-endpoint-seq">
     <property name="Authorization" expression="$trp:BackendToken" scope="transport"/>
</sequence>
```

Now, in your request, you need to send a header like this.

```
BackendToken: Bearer <Backend_Token>
```

Then it will be converted to below, inside the sequence and sent to the backend.

```
Authorization: Bearer <Backend_Token>
```

See below link for more details.

https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Adding+Mediation+Extensions

Comment: I updated my question with some additional information. Would you please have another look?

Comment: Sample working request to a backend will be helpful.

Comment: I can't give a working request for this particular backend, but it's just a standard `GET` request with an `Authorization` key/value pair in the header. 

Said `GET` request works in Postman or Fiddler, so I know the token is valid. 

Maybe (probably?) I'm not understanding the question.

Comment: Please enable wire logs. That will tell what the problem is. http://lakshanigamage.blogspot.com/2015/03/how-to-enable-wire-logs-in-wso2-esbapim.html

Comment: Enabled wire logs, pasted in dump from the request.

Comment: Are you sure you have `bearer` or `basic` part added in the key if it's required? I don't see any other issue with this. One more thing you can do is creating a request to backend with only information in the log and see if it works.

Comment: ...I did not have `bearer`. Good catch.