# Immortal token for backend API

Tags: wso2

The documentation for the API I need to connect to suggests creating an "immortal" token (that never expires) issued to an admin and then attaching that token to all requests. Here's a [detailed rundown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47559846/pass-a-custom-authorization-token-to-the-backend) on how that works. And it does work.

But it seems like a strange way to do it, but I'm not familiar enough with all of the concepts involved to say why.

Are there security concerns with going this route?

Answer (score 0):

I think my answer to the other question was not complete. I added some more details to the answer.